# Не выводится JPanel во фрейме

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Выдает пустое окно, хотя по задумке должны появиться кнопки и панель, в чем проблема? Все классы проекта работают исправно.

```
public class MainFrame implements ActionListener
{
    String directoryName = "C:/";
    String fileName = "";
    File curFile;//ссылка на текущий файл
    static JFrame frame;
    //JPanel pMain;//ссылка на главную панель фрейма
    Container pMain;
    JTable VIS_TABLE;//ссылка на визуальный компонент для вывода бд
    EditPanel editPanel;//ссылка на панель инструментов редактирования
    ViewPanel viewPanel;//ссылка на панель инструментов просмотра
    JLabel jFileName;//метка для вывода имени файла таблицы
    javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter filter; 
    static JLabel MSG;//метка для вывода сообщений в нижней части окна
    java.util.List<String> LINES;//ссылка на список сообщений для "справки"
    MainFrame mainFrame;
    static String helpArr1 = " ";
    static String helpArr2 = " ";

    public MainFrame(){
        Global.table = new ResultGroup();
        Global.results = new ArrayList<Result>();
        Global.tableModel = new ResultTableModel(Global.results);
        Global.start = 0;
        Global.end = 0;
        Global.mainFrame = mainFrame;
        VIS_TABLE = new JTable(Global.tableModel);
        JScrollPane scrtable = new JScrollPane(VIS_TABLE);//JScrollPane не ползунок!(а панель с возможностью перемещения по компоненту)
        VIS_TABLE.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(250, 100));//размер панели
        viewPanel = new ViewPanel();
        editPanel = new EditPanel();
        
        MenuIS menu = new MenuIS();
        
        pMain = new Container();
        pMain.add(menu.getJMenu(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pMain.add(editPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(pMain, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

public class Main
{
    public static void Main(){
        MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();
        mainFrame.OpenFile();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как минимум стоило бы добавить менеджер компоновки/расположения для панели

Менеджеры компоновки отвечают за то как и где будут будут располагаться и отрисовываться компоненты вашей формы.

Поэтому фрейм и не отображает ничего: он не знает где и как.

Для примера, `BoxLayout` просто располагает компоненты друг за другом в вертикальном либо горизонтальном положении:

```java
pMain.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pMain, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

В коде:

```java
public class MainFrame implements ActionListener
{
    String directoryName = "C:/";
    String fileName = "";
    File curFile;//ссылка на текущий файл
    static JFrame frame;
    //JPanel pMain;//ссылка на главную панель фрейма
    Container pMain;
    JTable VIS_TABLE;//ссылка на визуальный компонент для вывода бд
    EditPanel editPanel;//ссылка на панель инструментов редактирования
    ViewPanel viewPanel;//ссылка на панель инструментов просмотра
    JLabel jFileName;//метка для вывода имени файла таблицы
    javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter filter; 
    static JLabel MSG;//метка для вывода сообщений в нижней части окна
    java.util.List<String> LINES;//ссылка на список сообщений для "справки"
    MainFrame mainFrame;
    static String helpArr1 = " ";
    static String helpArr2 = " ";

    public MainFrame(){
        Global.table = new ResultGroup();
        Global.results = new ArrayList<Result>();
        Global.tableModel = new ResultTableModel(Global.results);
        Global.start = 0;
        Global.end = 0;
        Global.mainFrame = mainFrame;
        VIS_TABLE = new JTable(Global.tableModel);
        JScrollPane scrtable = new JScrollPane(VIS_TABLE);//JScrollPane не ползунок!(а панель с возможностью перемещения по компоненту)
        VIS_TABLE.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(250, 100));//размер панели
        viewPanel = new ViewPanel();
        editPanel = new EditPanel();
        
        MenuIS menu = new MenuIS();
        
        pMain = new Container();
        // ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
        pMain.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pMain, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        // ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
        pMain.add(menu.getJMenu(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pMain.add(editPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(pMain, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

public class Main
{
    public static void Main(){
        MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();
        mainFrame.OpenFile();
    }
}
```

**Ссылки:**

- Использование менеджеров компоновки [[документация Oracle]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)
- Swing Layouts [[статья на портале java online]](https://java-online.ru/swing-layout.xhtml)
- Примеры на [quizful](http://www.quizful.net/post/swing-layout-managers)